# FFMPEG using concat but process was killed no Error message

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am android devloper
I use FFmpeg for edit video.
use this library

https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android
just

```
FFmpeg.execute(" command ");
```

I use filter-complex, but  process was killed with no error

is this clue error message ?

```
"`[out_0_0 @ 000002092867e200] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.`"
```

Can you tell me how to fix it?
below is my command 
I think syntax is ok, but sementics is wrong.

```
-y -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/error_movie.mp4 -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=start=20.900:duration=14.500,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; 
[0:v]trim=start=0:duration=20.900,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; 
[0:v]trim=start=35.400:duration=30.300,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; 
[0:v]trim=start=20.900:duration=14.500,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4]; 
[0:v]trim=start=20.900:duration=14.500,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5]; 
[0:a]atrim=start=20.900:duration=14.500,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; 
[0:a]atrim=start=0:duration=20.900,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; 
[0:a]atrim=start=35.400:duration=30.300,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; 
[0:a]atrim=start=20.900:duration=14.500,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a4]; 
[0:a]atrim=start=20.900:duration=14.500,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a5]; 
[v1][v2][v3][v4][v5]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[ffmpegVideoOut];
[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]concat=n=5:v=0:a=1[ffmpegAudioOut]" 
-map [ffmpegVideoOut] -map [ffmpegAudioOut] 
/storage/emulated/0/AiTube/AiTube_20200316_103442.mp4
```

Comment: Show the complete log.

Comment: it was killed, and there is no log for killed app,
can  you tell me above comand is correct or not ?

Comment: Not able to verify command without the log (stderr output) from the ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 2):

when you are working with **FFMPEG** its a good idea to install it on your OS in order to make sure that your commands are correct

in your case the problem is in your command string

```
[0:a]atrim=start=0:duration=20.900,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
```

should be :

```
[0:a]atrim=start=0:duration=20.900,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
```

you have to use **asetpts** when you are using **atrim** filter

Comment: I didn't realize there was one wrong command.
You are really great.